# Event Droids look like normal Bitizens on my device

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

For some reason the Droids from the event appear "Human" on my device (also named Human) I am wondering if this will cause me any problems with unlocking the scene. Also if there is any way to get them to appear as they should be.

[image: human]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing this similar issue. Besides this, both Mustafar and Geonosis apts are grey in colour and look similar. Also, in Album > Scenes, Imperial Marches appear as ??? and its video scene is unplayable. I've reported the issue to the developer and was told to wait for a fix in an upcoming update. When will this update be available to us is a mystery though. I've tried rebooting the game, closing the and then rebooting the phone, etc but to no avail. We will just have to wait it seems.

Answer (score 0):

These types of glitches have been affecting Tiny Death Star since the most recent update.  People have reported seeing multiple errors with things like names, dream jobs, and even character appearances.

For the most part, exiting the game and restarting it has resolved these sorts of glitches.